# Как сделать такой фон?

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер, каким образом можно добить такого вот фона?
Как здесь например: http://www.worldofsocial.com/
Из того что догадываюсь, фон голубой повторяется а сверху просто затемнение?

Или вот здесь: http://momentskis.com/warranty/
Коричневый, тоже просто повторяется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body { background: url('pattern.png') repeat-repeat; }
#inner-body { background: url('drop-shadow.png') no-repeat center top; }
```